# Cut Method instead of copying filesC#

Tags: c#, copy

Can anyone help? I got a copy method for files but how do i cut files?
This is my copy code:`File.Copy(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to move the files without leaving the originals? Just use the [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) method instead:

```
File.Move(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
```

---

To overwrite an existing file, you'll want to employ [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) and [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) as well:

```
var source = FileBrowseBox.Text;
var target = Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(source)));

if (File.Exists(target))
{
    File.Delete(target);
}

File.Move(source, target);
```

Comment: @loko Glad to help. Happy coding. Oh, and don't let Jeff Atwood hear you call SO a 'forum'. See [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)

Comment: Luckily it's text, he can't hear text :D

Comment: @p.s.w.g  Do you guys happen to know how to replace a file when they have the same name?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud  Do you guys happen to know how to replace a file when they have the same name?

Comment: @loko, you have to use `File.Delete` first.

Comment: @loko, you would be deleting the destination file. So the second path you provide to `Move`, use that same path for `Delete`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud but the destination PATH isn't showing a file

Comment: @loko check for the file first with [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) and use [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) if necessary.

Comment: @p.s.w.g can you explain me how both of them work? i clicked on the methods but if i use File.Exists() What should be between the "()"

Comment: @p.s.w.g Well? Can you help? :S

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud can you explain me how both of them work? i clicked on the methods What should be between the "()"

Comment: @loko See my updated answer for an example on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Dont know how but thanks anyway.  I did exactly the same except i didn't use "var target" and "var source"